# Select posts and tags in a single query

Tags: mysql, select

If I have 3 tables:

**posts**

post_id
title
body

**tags**

tag_id
name

**posts_tags**

post_id
tag_id

What is the best way to list (select) the posts and the tags for each of them from a single query?

Comment: I don't understand why the negative votes. I wanted to know if there is a way to get all the tags for a post, without returning more than one time the post id, body, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply join the three tables. If you use left join, you will also see which posts don't have tags.

```
SELECT *
FROM posts 
LEFT JOIN posts_tags ON posts.post_id = posts_tags.post_id
LEFT JOIN tags ON posts_tags.tag_id = tags.tag_id
```

Comment: So there is no way to get all the tags for a post, without returning more than one time the post id, body, etc.
This is what I wanted to know.

Comment: It's possible, too: instead of "SELECT *", write "SELECT tags.name", and at the and of the query append a filter expression "WHERE posts.post_id = 1".